# MaiKit ImapClient wrong encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, mailkit

I'm using MailKit library to read emails from MS Exchange mailbox. Here is my code

```cs
var client = new ImapClient();

///...

client.Authenticate(saslMechanism);
client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);
var items = client.Inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.All | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure);

foreach(var item in items) {
    
    // Here I had wron decoded characters in some emails 
    Console.WriteLine(item.Envelope.Subject);
}

/// ...
```

The encoding is wrong in some messages.

Is there any way to force the mailkit to re-encode messages in a certain encoding when received from the server

Comment: Try to use MailKit in version 3.3.0. This was last version I had correct encoding in my messages. Since then there are wrongly displayed national characters. Do not why, do not how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem like this
Downgraded MailKit NuGet package vestion to 2.15.0

```
<PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="2.15.0" />
```

Prior to this, the project used the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not.

The Envelope data structure does not keep the raw byte data received from the server, so it cannot try deciding it again using a different charset encoding.

What you *can* do is modify your Fetch request to get the Subject header (in addition to or instead of the Envelope) and then use:

```
int index = item.Headers.IndexOf(HeaderId.Subject);
Header header = item.Headers[index];
string subject = header.GetValue(“charset name goes here”);
```